# initialize firebase app in multiple files with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to Initialize **Firebase** App in multiple files to organize my methods properly, but I not sure which is the best way to do so.

Below is the file system structure:

```
/functions
 |-keys
 |-methods
 |  |-email.js
 |  |-logger.js
 |-node_modules
 |-index.js
 |-package.json
 |-package-lock.json
```

In my index.js, I initialize 2 projects where 1 is for production and another is for OTE.:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');

var productionServiceAccount = require('./keys/production-key.json');
var oteServiceAccount = require("./keys/ote-key.json");

var prodServer = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(productionServiceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://production-panel.firebaseio.com'
}, "prod");
var oteServer = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(oteServiceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://ote-panel.firebaseio.com"
}, "ote");

console.log("prodServer: ", prodServer.name, "oteServer: ", oteServer.name)

var mailer = require('./methods/email.js') //import code from method folder
var logger = require('./methods/logger.js') //import code from method folder
```

Below is how i handle the request whether use prod or OTE project:

```
let admin = req.headers.env == 'prod' ? prodServer : oteServer
```

Now the problem is my `./methods/logger.js` want to read/write log into DB as well, but I don't know how/what to do.

```
Below is the `logger.js` code:
var exports = {}

exports.log = function(item, ref, env) {
    let admin = env == 'prod' ? prodServer : oteServer //<--problem here

    return admin.database().ref(ref).push(item)
}

module.exports = exports
```

Should I initialize firebase project again or import it from `index.js`?

-If initialize firebase project again it will say the project "name" has been used.

-If import it from `index.js`, then I have to export it from `index.js`, which when I deploy it to Firebase Function, it will become an onCall Methods..?

-If I move the initialize to another file (./method/initFirebase.js) and import it to `index.js` when I deploy it to Firebase Function, will it automatically initialize the firebase app?

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create one additional file like you said `initFirebase.js` and put your initilization and export code there.

```
const prodServer = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(productionServiceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://production-panel.firebaseio.com',
}, 'prod');
const oteServer = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(oteServiceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://ote-panel.firebaseio.com',
}, 'ote');
module.exports = {
    firebaseApp: env === 'prod' ? prodServer : oteServer,
};
```

And from all other file import firebase app

```
const firebaseApp = require('../YOUR_initFirebase.js')
```

So you dont need to worry about environment in each of the files and it is working for me on google cloud functions.

Comment: will the `initFirebase.js` successfully export when the `env` is not declare in the file? My `env` mostly come in together with the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can manage multiple apps with firebase-admin on nodejs to ensure the apps are not reinitialised.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const service1 = require('./app1-service.json');
const service2 = require('./app2-service.json');

const apps = {
  app1: null,
  app2: null,
};

void init() {
  // check and init app1
  const initialisedApps = admin.apps.map((item) => item.name);
  if (!initialisedApps.includes('app1')) {
    apps.app1 = admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(service1),
    }, 'app1');
  } else apps.app1 = admin.app('app1');
  
  // check and init app2
  if (!initialisedApps.includes('app2')) {
    apps.app2 = admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(service2),
    }, 'app2');
  } else apps.app2 = admin.app('app2');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this for ts is:

**index.ts**

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.auth = require('./methods/email.ts');

...
```

**email.ts**

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

// Get emails
exports.getEMail = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  const uid = context?.auth?.uid ? context.auth.uid : '';
  const email = await admin.firestore().collection('emails').doc(uid).get();

  return email;
...
```